# Unable to access BeagleBone Black GPIO

Tags: c, debian, overlay, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I have a BeagleBone Black board and I'm using the below-mentioned image file.
https://debian.beagleboard.org/images/bone-debian-10.3-iot-armhf-2020-04-06-4gb.img.xz

I aim to operate GPIO pins of this board with the c programming language.

To do so, I've gone through this link: https://beagleboard.org/static/librobotcontrol/installation.html

And after following all the steps according to this link the result I achieved is the same as mentioned in the checking functionality step [the last step] of this document.

Furthermore, I follow this document for c language setup:
https://github.com/beagleboard/librobotcontrol/blob/master/docs/src/project_template.dox

and run this source code:
https://beagleboard.org/static/librobotcontrol/rc_test_leds_8c-example.html

All these processes were completed without any error.

##################################
Now I want to access the GPIO pins of the board. For that, I've prepared a basic code.

Let's take a pin P8_10 / GPIO2[4] for an example. So for that my code will be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <rc/led.h>
#include <rc/gpio.h>
#include <rc/time.h>
//#define WAIT_US 500000 // time to light each LED in microseconds
int main()
{
rc_gpio_init(2,4,GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_OUTPUT); /* declare as output*/
rc_gpio_set_value(2,4,1); /* set high */
rc_gpio_cleanup(2,4);
    return 0;
}
```

After executing this code I am not getting the expected output.

So have you any suggestions for me regarding this code.
Or is there any other way to do so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try config-pin  gpio

```
config-pin p9.9 gpio
```

Then try your source. If that does not work and if getting the gpio pins muxed on the BBB is giving you issues. You can always test your specific pin w/:

```
config-pin -q <Your Specific Pin Used>
```

For instance: `config-pin -q p9.9` will tell you how it is muxed.

Also, most pins can be found by a testing script by mvduin.

Here is the site online at github: https://github.com/mvduin/bbb-pin-utils

Here: https://beagleboard.org/Support/bone101

That site, once scrolling downward, shows a bunch of different ways to mux your BBB w/ GPIO, i2c, UART, and so on...

This and more can be a good base for working w/ the BBB outside of programming w/ the C language under the librobotcontrol library.

Also, here is a good starter on the way GPIO is handled in the C lib. in question: https://beagleboard.org/librobotcontrol/group___g_p_i_o.html